# Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: android-studio, condiciones, else

bueno tengo un problema simple que no logro resolver pero me precisa solucionarlo.

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que me lance un mensaje que diga "campos vacios" cuando el usuario no ingrese nada. pero me da un error en la linea donde convierto el int.

> int Cantidad = Integer.parseInt(Cant.getText().toString());
> int Precio = Integer.parseInt(Pre.getText().toString());

Aqui voy a dejar el codigo donde hago los if y los else diganme si los implemente mal, que es lo mas seguro y como solucionar el problema.

```
public void GuardarProducto(View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_guardar:
                String Nombre = NomP.getText().toString();
                int Cantidad = Integer.parseInt(Cant.getText().toString());
                int Precio = Integer.parseInt(Pre.getText().toString());

                BDproductos DB = new BDproductos(this, "DBUsuarios", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = DB.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues nuevoregistro = new ContentValues();
                nuevoregistro.put("nombreP", Nombre);
                nuevoregistro.put("cantidad", Cantidad);
                nuevoregistro.put("precio", Precio);
                long i = sqLiteDatabase.insert("PRODUCTOS", null, nuevoregistro);
                if (i > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Registro Insertado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(AgregarProductos.this, PantallaPrincipal.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                    finish();
                    break;
                } else if (i == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Los Campos estan Vacios", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el usuario no introduce nada, se produce un error al tratar de convertir en `int` una cadena vacía. Por tanto, antes de convertir las entradas de precio y cantidad a `int` tendrás que comprobar que no son una cadena vacía, y de serlo, generar el mensaje de advertencia correspondiente. Y probablemente también quieras considerar la posibilidad de que el usuario introduzca otras cadenas no convertibles a enteros.

Luego, en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) de `SQLiteDatabase.insert` dice que el valor que devuelve está función será -1 si es un error, por lo que sería esa posibilidad la que tendrías que chequear.

El código quedaría así:

```
public void GuardarProducto(View view){
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_guardar:
            String Nombre = NomP.getText().toString();
            String entradaCantidad = Cant.getText().toString();
            String entradaPrecio = Pre.getText().toString();

            // Chequeamos las cadenas de texto
            if (entradaCantidad.isEmpty() || entradaPrecio.isEmpty() || Nombre.isEmpty() ){
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Los Campos no pueden estar vacíos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
            int Cantidad;
            int Precio;
            try {
                Cantidad = Integer.parseInt(entradaCantidad);
                Precio = Integer.parseInt(entradaPrecio);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Los Campos PRECIO y CANTIDAD deben ser números enteros", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }

            BDproductos DB = new BDproductos(this, "DBUsuarios", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = DB.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues nuevoregistro = new ContentValues();
            nuevoregistro.put("nombreP", Nombre);
            nuevoregistro.put("cantidad", Cantidad);
            nuevoregistro.put("precio", Precio);
            long i = sqLiteDatabase.insert("PRODUCTOS", null, nuevoregistro);
            if (i == -1) {
                // Falló la inserción
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: No se pudo guardar el producto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            } 
            // Si llegamos aquí, es que la inserción tuvo éxito
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registro Insertado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i2 = new Intent(AgregarProductos.this, PantallaPrincipal.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono perfectamente.